# I am miscalculating the Asymptotic Bode Plot

Tags: control-system, matlab, bode-plot, frequency-response

hope you are all doing well. Right now I am dealing with a homework and I have transfer function and I need to plot the asymptotic Bode Plots of it. I am trying to plot the Magnitude Diagram right now, and I am misevaluating the Magnitude at Low Frequencies. I calculate it as approximately 15dB, whereas MATLAB shows it 35 dB. Here is what I did:

[image]

The original question:

[image]

What am I missing? I am pretty ill right now, so I am probably missing out a detail, even though I checked it multiple times.

Comment: +1 for identifying this as homework and showing what you have tried.

Comment: question. what is log_10 of 6? What is 20 times that?

Comment: It is approximately 15.

Comment: my mistake, wrong hint.

Comment: There is a pole at origin indicated by the single `s` present in the denominator. You need to account for its effect also apart from the 15 dB you calculated. In fact, what do you mean by low frequency? When we substitute `s=0`, we get infinite, right?

Comment: Please post the original question exactly as given. Use the [edit] link below the question to add that info.

Comment: Added the question.

Comment: I assume that you are trying to plot the asymptotic bode for the *open loop* system. In that case, there is a pole at the origin and so the zero frequency gain is infinite. You can check by substituting `s=0` in the third equation. Due to the pole at origin, the asymptote is a sloping line with —20 dB/decade slope until it reaches the first corner frequency. You can verify by substituting 0.00001 rad/s, 0.0001 rad/s etc for `s` in the third equation. Matlab result may be wrong. What does `dcgain(openlooptransferfunction)` give a as output in matlab?

Comment: You are absolutely right, I forgot that the component coming from 1/s with -20 db/dec slope starts from infinity. So, the magnitude is at 20 db at 0.1 rad/sec.Adding that yields 35 db at 0.1 rad/s. I did not pay attention to that. Thank you so much for pointing it out.

Comment: If your original question is answered, you can post it as an answer yourself. It is allowed on this site.

Comment: @kucar I'm not sure I understand. Are you supposed to work with the closed loop solution, A/(1+A*B), or supposed to work with something else? (It doesn't seem to me that it wants an open loop to any particular place but instead the closed loop result. But what do I know?)

Comment: @jonk In the lessons we dealt with the open loop transfer functions, therefore I assumed that this one require me to deal with the open loop system too. I asked my friends about it and they confirmed me. However, you might be right, I will ask my lecturer about it. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what was I missing thanks to everyone who commented. I was not taking the pole at the origin into account. However, the magnitude of this pole starts with a slope of -20dB/decade at infinity, and at w = 0.1 rad/s, it is at 20 dB magnitude. Adding that 20 dB to the 15 dB I had already calculated, yields the starting magnitude as 35 dB, just like on MATLAB. Big thanks to everyone who helped!